# mousedown event not working on dynamicallyadded elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to user mousedown event on dynamically added elements

```js
$(function() {
  var isMouseDown = false,
    isHighlighted;
  //$('#our_table').on('mousedown', 'tr', function (event) {
  $("#myTable tr").mousedown(function() {
    isMouseDown = true;
    $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
    isHighlighted = $(this).hasClass("highlighted");
    return false; // prevent text selection
  }).mouseover(function() {
    if (isMouseDown) {
      $(this).toggleClass("highlighted", isHighlighted);
    }
  }).bind("selectstart", function() {
    return false;
  })
  $(document).mouseup(function() {
    isMouseDown = false;
  });
});

function addRow() {
  var arrTables = document.getElementById('myTable');
  var oRows = arrTables.rows;
  var numRows = oRows.length;

  var newRow = document.getElementById('myTable').insertRow(numRows);
  var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);

  cell1.innerHTML = numRows;
  cell2.innerHTML = numRows;
  cell3.innerHTML = numRows;
}
```

```css
table td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

table tr.highlighted td {
  background-color: #999;
}

body {
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onclick="addRow()">Add Row</button>
```

Comment: Use the $('document').on('mousedown','.class_info',function(){. Your dynamic content even loaded isnt part of the dom.

Comment: It's always better to add the code required in the question. But I can see your fault - you need to use 'delegated' watchers on your elements. Not a `mousedown`. You commented-out the correct method above your mousedown function handler

Comment: Thanks Cam, If you open that link - http://jsfiddle.net/AbhiThakare/vqbnkfhL/  I have trie that as well.

Comment: @Glycerine, even if I use .on methond (commented code) still it is not wokring, some how $(this) refers to wrong elements and heance row is not selected.

Comment: It works fine when you use `on()` correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/xarwj7c1/

Comment: Thanks Rory, but if I use ```on()``` my rows are not selected on mouse drag.

Comment: In which case see @n1kkou's answer below

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the event delegation to `body` element and then match the event.target to the element you want to trigger your action.

You can check this start, updated your fiddle only for the mousedown method: http://jsfiddle.net/Len7csa0/

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Len7csa0/

Comment: My point is you need to actually complete you're answer. All it does right now is describe the solution which isn't really helpful.

Comment: And also the rest of the methods should be hooked and updated the same, but I don't know the full description of what methods should be modified except what is specified in the question(mousedown). True, about what you said, I will also update the solution.

Comment: sorry @n1kkou but dynamic added row is not selected on mouse drag.

Comment: Try to find the complete answer in the duplicate link, it might help you a lot!